# MySQL DELETE in a single table

Tags: sql, database, mysql

I have a database with only one table as below:

```
userurltag(id,userID(string),Url(String),tag(String))
```

I want to delete users that have less than 3 urls associated with them.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one:

```
DELETE
    FROM userurltag USING userurltag
    JOIN
        (SELECT userID
         FROM userurltag
         GROUP BY userID HAVING COUNT(*) < 3) as tmp
ON userurltag.userID = tmp.userID;
```

Comment: Replace "user_id" with "userid" and "t.userid" with "userurltag.userid" and this should work.

Comment: @Ike Walker: you are right, I played with a slightly different table structure and did not modify the query thoroughly =)

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE 
FROM userurltag 
WHERE UserID IN 
(SELECT UserID FROM userurltag GROUP BY userID Having COUNT(UserID) < 3)
```